# Resetting the aim in Pikmin 3 Deluxe (demo)

Tags: pikmin-3

I have played Pikmin 3 on the WiiU, and as such become very accustomed to motion aiming. Thus, when playing through the Switch demo, I similarly activated gyro controls. This aim drifts, especially when spamming the throw button. Is there a nice way to reset the aim?

I remember Splatoon 2 had a button for it, but I can't find one in Pikmin 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the gyro controls where the motion set the cursor location, I believe the button to press is R1. I know its one of the shoulder buttons.

Comment: You're right. R1 did the trick. The controller overview said that R1 and L1 both swap pikmin type (and I know they both do if you deactivate gyro). Guess that's just an oversight from Nintendo.